# What is the title of this Dragonlance Adventure partly set on one of Krynn's moons?

Tags: adnd-2e, product-identification, dragonlance

I read a description of this in a pamphlet describing the various D&D settings that came out in 1998. But I no longer remember the title.

The module in question was a Dragonlance adventure, and the description said at least some of the action occurred on one of Krynn's moons- which one wasn't specified, but I suspect it was Nuitari, if for no other reason the 'evil' moon seemed a place where heroes would most likely battle hostile beings.

The description did say PCs on the moon would encounter living beings "made of wire" (sounds weird I know, but that's how my faded memory recalls it) and referred to the adventure as exploring the "strangest parts of the Dragonlance mythos".

Does anyone know the title of this adventure?

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are looking for "DLE2: Dragon Magic."

From the Wikipedia description: "Dragon Magic is a Dragonlance scenario where the player characters take a journey to a cloud city, get sent through a portal to Krynn's moon of Lunitari, and stop the forces of evil from slaying the Celestial Dragon of Neutrality."

PS. If this isn't it, [here is a list of all Dragonlance modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_modules_and_sourcebooks).